# Imagic пакетное изменение размера

Tags: imagick

Я нашел вот такой скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

 # абсолютный путь к папке с изображениями
FOLDER="/home/httpd/vhosts/bali-tai.ru/subdomains/test/httpdocs/upload/shop_3"

 # высота изображения
WIDTH=205

 # ширина изображения
HEIGHT=205

 # размер по высоте или ширине, держим пропорции, используя imagemagick
#find $FOLDER -iname 'small_item_*.jpg' -o -iname 'small_item_*.png' -exec convert {} -resize $WIDTHx$HEIGHT> {} \;
#find ${FOLDER} -iname 'small_item_*.jpg' -exec convert \{} -verbose -resize $WIDTHx$HEIGHT\> \{} \;
find ${FOLDER} -iname 'item_*.jpg' -o -iname 'item_*.png' -exec convert \{} -verbose -resize $WIDTHx$HEIGHT\> \{} \;
```

Но он как то не так работает. Он зачем то создает папку thumbs и помещает преобразованные изображения туда. Но это пол беды, некоторые изображения он режет не 205х205, как задано в настройках, а  205x139. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: 1. *Он зачем то создает папку thumbs* — в скрипте про это ничего нет. и программа convert так не ведёт себя по умолчанию (возможно, её попатчили для такого странного поведения). 2. *режет* — про это в скрипте тоже ничего нет. программе convert указывается делать **resize**, но не **crop** или что-либо подобное, что можно было бы охарактеризовать словом «режет». 3. если вам не нужно сохранять пропорции, то добавьте [квантификатор `!`](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html)

Comment: Т.е если мне надо, чтобы скрипт делал ресайз по высоте например, а по ширине делал кроп, Мне оффсетами надо это регулировать, или это можно сделать как-то еще ?